# Non Markov chain process.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples

Consider $\xi_n $ are independent, non-negative, equal distributed random variables. Let $S_n = \xi_1 + \dots + \xi_n$. Let $N_t = \max \{n : S_n \le t\}$.

Does there example of such process, which isn't a Markov process?

Comment: $N_t$ is a renewal process, which in general is not a Markov process.

Comment: @Math1000 any example?